# jquery - how to add an variable as an id in jquery command.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Its a simple question, could not find an answer from google.

Code

```
$.click(function(){
var curID = $(this).parent()[0].id;
$("#"+curID input).attr("checked",true);
});
```

Onclick function is giving me the parent id, Now, using the parent id i want to find the input element and add checked attribute.

I am not sure of the syntax of querying by `dynamic ID`.

I want to know how can i query by dynamic variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML as wel? I'm having difficulties understanding what it is your asking..

Comment: `$.click` is going to throw an error, since that function doesn't exist. You need to actually select elements to bind the click event to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#"+curID).find('input').attr("checked", true);
```

Or

```
$(this).parent().find('input').attr("checked", true);
```

Or

```
$('input', $(this).parent()).find('input').attr("checked", true); // using the scope argument
```

Answer (score 2):

The selectors are strings... So should be handled as strings by concatenating the variables: and texts

```
$.click(function(){
var curID = $(this).parent()[0].id;
$("#"+curID+" input").attr("checked",true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your search is probably too specific. Break tasks down into their components instead of looking for a complete solution to a very specific problem. You are just dealing with basic string concatenation here.

You want:

```
var selector = "#foo input";
```

You have `foo` in a variable.

```
var selector = "#" + foo_variable + " input";
```